# $L^{⟨Gal(L/F),Gal(L,F’)⟩}=F \cap F'$

Tags: group-theory, galois-extensions

Let $L/k $ be a Galois extension. If $F$ and $F'$ are intermediate fields of $L/k$ then

$L^{⟨Gal(L/F),Gal(L,F’)⟩}=F \cap F'$

($⟨G;G′⟩$ is used to denote the subgroup generated by $H ∪ H′.$)

Using some theorems we have that

$F=L^{Gal(L/F)}$ ;  $F'= L^{Gal(L,F’)}$

$ L^{Gal(L/F)} \cap L^{Gal(L,F’)}$

What do I need to do to connect the dots to finish the question or is it already finished and I didn't notice.

Comment: The subgroup $H$ of $G := \mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$ generated by $H_1 := \mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ and $H_2 := \mathrm{Gal}(L/F')$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $H_1$ and $H_2$. Thus, by Galois correspondence, the fixed field of $H$ is the largest field contained in both $F$ and $F'$, that is, $F \cap F'$.

Comment: It was "already finished".

Comment: Please do not use titles that are entirely MathJax.